# Testing for and parsing JSON response in Node.js/Express.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

A Node.js server running Express.js handles an `HTTP GET` to `mydomain.com/myurl` by sending a `POST` to `http://some_other_domain_url_with_params?reply_url=mydomain.com/myurl`.  And the response comes back as simply JSON.

**What code needs to be added to the routes.js file below in order to:

1.) create a separate handling block in the event that a request for mydomain.com/myurl is only JSON, and

2.) transfer the JSON response elements manually by name into variable1, variable2, variable3, etc.?**

Here is `routes.js`, which handles the server-side routes:

```
var url = require('url');

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/myurl', function(req, res) {
        app.post('http://some_other_domain_url_with_params?reply_url=mydomain.com/myurl', function(req, res) {});
        console.log('The POST is finished.  Waiting for response.');
        //need separate handler for JSON response that comes back from the other domain after this
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
    });
};
```

The response from `POST http://some_other_domain_url_with_params?reply_url=mydomain.com/myurl` might look like:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "var_one":"value1",
   "var_two":"value2",
   "var_three":1100
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `app.post` call wont do a POST reqqest to another server, it is for setting up a POST route on your server. If you want to make HTTP requests to another server, it's esiest to use a library like [request](https://github.com/request/request). Then you can use `JSON.parse` to turn the response JSON into a native JavaScript object.

Example:

```
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/myurl', function(req, res) {
        request.post('http://some_other_domain_url_with_params?reply_url=mydomain.com/myurl', function(err, response, body){
            if(err){
                //handle error here
            }
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            var variable1 = data.var_one;
            var variable2 = data.var_two;
            var variable3 = data.var_three;
            //Do more processing here
        });
        console.log('The POST is finished.  Waiting for response.');
    });
};
```

Comment: This works.  However, do not forget: `npm install --save request`